Can LTspice express the result of a phase measurement in degrees?
I will ask my question through the following example to make it simpler.
I have the following directive to find the minimum phase value:
.meas AC Phase_min MIN Ph(V(Vout))

It works fine apart from the fact that the phase is expressed in dB rather than in degrees, here is the program output:
phase_min: MIN(ph(v(vout)))=(36.9694dB,0�) FROM 1 TO 1e+06

A phase expressed in dB is not very meaningful so my question:
Can anybody tell me how to set LTspice to obtain it in degrees (rather than in dB)? Or, if not possible, a workaround?

The following figure is a follow up after some comments, to give a practical example of my question. It illustrates the LTspice results.


Maybe "find" will work?  example: .meas AC f1 find V(out) when mag(V(out))=0.707 cross=1

If you add the following SPICE directive, does it change anything?  .options meascplxfmt=cartesian

To get the phase expressed in degrees it is necessary to add the following directive:
.options meascplxfmt=cartesian

(suggested in Ste Kulov comment Nov 21 at 4:56)
The option above actually gives real and imaginary part of measurements that has a a complex number as a result. The units are linear and not in dB. That is why the option works in the case of my question.
However, this option will show other measured complex quantities in the same format, which may not be the most convenient, as e.g. if you are measuring a transfer function Vout/Vin magnitude.
